# How to fix dplyr filter() Error in UseMethod("filter_")

Tags: r, select, dplyr

When I try to select a data from the data matrix that I have created I receive an error, I would like that someone can help me out and fix it.

> Error in UseMethod("filter_") :    no applicable method for 'filter_'
>   applied to an object of class "c('matrix', 'double', 'numeric')"

I have tried to call out the function by doing dplyr::
or by using some pipe operations mydata %>% filter(2010)  or even installed and loaded package "conflicted" and gave the dplyr an priority but nothing works. I am new with r.

```
Matrix_5c_AVG_Year  <- cbind(AVG_SWE_YEAR,AVG_NO[,2],AVG_FI[,2],AVG_EE[,2],AVG_LV[,2],AVG_LT[,2])
colnames(Matrix_5c_AVG_Year) <- c("Year","AVG_SWE1", "AVG_NO1", "AVG_FI1", "AVG_EE1", "AVG_LV1", "AVG_LT1") 
mydata<-Matrix_5c_AVG_Year  
mydata %>% filter(2010)
```

I would like to get an output of only the row of 2010 data and perferably be able to select only one header.

Comment: It is good practice to include a subset of your data or a representative sample of your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by @brettljausn, you need to convert your matrix to a data.frame. You will also get an error in the call to `filter` if you do not add the column name on which you want to compare your conditional value.

This should work illustrate your problem and a solution (continuing in tidyverse, since you are using `filter`):

```r
library(tidyverse)


(a <- matrix(c(5,1), 2, 2))
#>      [,1] [,2]
#> [1,]    5    5
#> [2,]    1    1

colnames(a) <- c("Year", "AVG_SWE1")

a %>%
  filter(Year == 5)
#> Error in UseMethod("filter_"): no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "c('matrix', 'double', 'numeric')"

(a2 <- as_tibble(a))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>    Year AVG_SWE1
#>   <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1     5        5
#> 2     1        1

a2 %>%
  filter(Year == 5)
#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>    Year AVG_SWE1
#>   <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1     5        5
```

<sup>Created on 2019-07-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Since you are new, I would recommend you to read chapter 1-16 of https://r4ds.had.co.nz/.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion but it still outputs the same error ""> mydata %>% filter(Year == 2010)
Error in UseMethod("filter_") : 
  no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "c('matrix', 'double', 'numeric')" is there any way how to get rid of it?

Comment: I'm guessing `cbind(AVG_SWE_YEAR,AVG_NO[,2],AVG_FI[,2],AVG_EE[,2],AVG_LV[,2],AVG_LT[,2])` returns a matrix and not a dataframe. maybe try `Matrix_5c_AVG_Year  <- data.frame(AVG_SWE_YEAR,AVG_NO[,2],AVG_FI[,2],AVG_EE[,2],AVG_LV[,2],AVG_LT[,2])` instead

Comment: It gives the same error. But I will try by exporting the matrix to excel and then importing it into a new r project and I hope that it will fix the issue.

Comment: It is very hard to help you without understanding more about your data and setup. I have changed my answer to reflect, to the best of my ability and with the input from @brettljausn, what I believe is your problem and a solution. Also - what was your solution?

Comment: Thanks, you helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to larsoevlisen I understood that my data are as an matrix and can not be manipulated in that way so I had to transform them into an `data.frame()` to filter the data I need out.

Final solution:

```
Matrix_5c_AVG_Year  < cbind(AVG_SWE_YEAR,AVG_NO_YEAR[,2],AVG_FI_YEAR[,2],AVG_EE_YEAR[,2],AVG_LV_YEAR[,2],AVG_LT_YEAR[,2])
 Matrix_5c_AVG_Year  <-data.frame(Matrix_5c_AVG_Year)
colnames(Matrix_5c_AVG_Year) <- c("Year","AVG_SWE1", "AVG_NO1",
"AVG_FI1", "AVG_EE1", "AVG_LV1", "AVG_LT1")
```