# Timeseries graphs of mean values of group in R

Tags: r

I am learning R and dealing a data set of with multiple repetitive columns, say 200 times as given columns are repeated 200 times.

[image]

I want to take mean of each column and the group the mean of each variable. So there will be 200 values of mean of each variable. I want to make a [line chart](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vEutvapch4EaukgD-hCD1O43Acw90awg/view?usp=sharing) like this of mean values of each variable.
I am trying these codes

```
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(viridisLite)

df <- read.table("H-W.csv", sep = ",")
df
dat  %>% filter(Scenario != 'NULL') %>%
  mutate("Scenario" = ifelse(Scenario == 'NULL2', "BASELINE", Scenario)) %>%
  group_by(.dots = c("X.step.", "Scenario"))  %>%        
  summarise('height.people' = mean(height), 
            'weight.people' = mean(weight), 
            "wealth.people" = mean(wealth)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(c('height.people', 'weight.people', 'wealth.people')) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = X.step., y = value, colour = Scenario)) + 
  geom_line(size = 1) + facet_grid(name~., scales = "free_y") + theme_classic() +
  scale_colour_viridis_d() + scale_y_log10()
```

I found this error

Error in UseMethod("filter") :
no applicable method for 'filter' applied to an object of class "NULL"

Comment: You read the data in `df` (`df <- read.table("H-W.csv", sep = ",")`) and then you are using `dat %>%....` shouldn't that be `df %>% ...` ?

Comment: Hi Ronak. I tried with df instead dat %>%, it gives the following error                
 Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
x object 'Scenario' not found
i Input `..1` is `Scenario != "NULL"

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have the same problem as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57286838/how-to-fix-dplyr-filter-error-in-usemethodfilter)...

Is your data in a data.frame or tibble?

Other wise if that doesn't work try this...

filter is a function in stats and dplyr,
so you could try changing

```
dat  %>% filter(Scenario != 'NULL') %>%
```

to

```
dat %>% dplyr::filter(Scenario != "NULL") %>%
```

Comment: It gives the same error rror in UseMethod("filter") : 
  no applicable method for 'filter' applied to an object of class "NULL"